# Is it possible to make a cURL request using html textarea?

Tags: php

Hi Im trying to develop an html application that can send request to a web server through the use of php cURL, my problem is whenever i test it out i get an error of a Reserved XML Name, Im using a form with a post method btw.

The weird thing is when I input the xml as string in php it works but through the use of html via post method I get that error. Isn't the input type value already a string so It should have the same results as the hardcoded xml string in php right?

The application uses the html file for UI so that users can edit the values inside the xml and through the use of post method it calls a cURL request inside my php script. was my approach wrong if so is there another method to make such requests?

sample of my code:

```
if($_POST['option'] == "SmacMembers"){
  $member= ($_POST['gmember']);
  echo $member;
  $URL = "https://localhost/globe2smac-fh3/api/";
  $ch = curl_init($URL);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "michael:kel");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('ContentType:text/xml'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $member);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  echo $output;
  }
```

and the sample XML request via textarea

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE OlsRequestFormat SYSTEM "OlsRequestFormat.dtd">
<methodCall>
<methodName>smac.members</methodName>
<params>
<param>
<value>
<string>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<globetosmac>
<functioncode>smac_members</functioncode>
<cardnumber>8880999521960565</cardnumber>
<transaction_id>12345678</transaction_id>
</globetosmac>
</string>
</value>
</param>
</params>
</methodCall>
```

Comment: Have you tried to urlencode() your textarea response before sending it to the service?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I've tried that one just now it gave me a different error now it says Empty document Ive implemented that one by using $member= urlencode($_POST['gmember']); where the $member var will be the one pass to curlopt_POSTFIELDS.

Comment: hmm i was able to get rid of the error but the problem by adding a content length to my curlopt_httpheader however im not sure if it's processing the request because it's taking a long time to load.

Comment: did some changes with my curl script now I'm encountering an error regarding an Invalid document end at line 1 column 1 is there an invisible whitespace I don't know about?

Comment: hmm disregard this question I was able to find the answer to it by myself :), cheers for the views